# Full site navigation links rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a full site navigation sidebar for my website, that allows you to access most (if not all) pages from any other page in the website. The problem I'm running into: it is getting rediculously complex, and not even working 100% of the time.

I have model User, Foo which belongs to User, and Bar which belongs to Foo.  So my site navigation for just the Foo index for example, looks like this in my helper file:

```
  def foo_index_link(text)
    if current_user == nil
        nil
        elsif @user != nil && @user.id != nil
            if @user.standard_name != nil
            if current_user.admin? || current_user.super_admin?
                    link_to @user.standard_name, admin_user_foos_path(@user)
            elsif current_user.standard?
                    link_to @user.standard_name, member_user_foos_path(@user)
                end
            else
            if current_user.admin? || current_user.super_admin?
                    link_to text, admin_user_foos_path(@user)
            elsif current_user.standard?
                    link_to text, member_user_foos_path(@user)
                end
        end     
      elsif @foo != nil && @foo.id != nil
            if @foo.user.standard_name != nil
            if current_user.admin? || current_user.super_admin?
                    link_to @foo.user.standard_name, admin_user_foos_path(@foo.user)
            elsif current_user.standard?
                    link_to @foo.user.standard_name, member_user_foos_path(@foo.user)
                end
            else
            if current_user.admin? || current_user.super_admin?
                    link_to text, admin_user_foos_path(@foo.user)
            elsif current_user.standard?
                    link_to text, member_user_foos_path(@foo.user)
                end
            end
    elsif @bar != nil && @bar.id != nil
            if @bar.foo.user.standard_name != nil
            if current_user.admin? || current_user.super_admin?
                    link_to @bar.foo.user.standard_name, admin_user_foos_path(@bar.foo.user)
            elsif current_user.standard?
                    link_to @bar.foo.user.standard_name, member_user_foos_path(@bar.foo.user)
                end
            else
            if current_user.admin? || current_user.super_admin?
                    link_to text, admin_user_foos_path(@bar.foo.user)
            elsif current_user.standard?
                    link_to text, member_user_foos_path(@bar.foo.user)
                end
            end
    else
        nil
    end
  end
```

((Obviously I changed the names, so don't mind minor typos))

Not only is this rediculously long to account for whatever page the user might currently be on, it also doesn't work for partials, since partials use local varibles like foo instead of @foo.

There has to be a better way to approach this, but I haven't really found one yet.  I'm ready to redesign my approach, just need some advice. Have any?

EDIT (more clarification):

My User, Foo, and Bar are all nested, separate models.  My config/routes for example:

```
namespace :member do
  resources :users do
    resources :foos
  end
  resources :foos do
    resources :bars
  end
end
```

My intention is to have a _sidebar.html.erb file that is part of the application layout, and has links to various other parts of the site. The problem I have, is that the links are dependent on the current pages resources.  For instance:

If I want to link to the bar index while at a bar show page, the link would be:

```
link_to "bar index", member_foo_bars_path(@bar)
```

But the same link while at the foo index page would be:

```
link_to "bar index", member_foo_bars_path(@foo)
```

And even worse, if you are on a partial, they don't have access to instance variables, so @bar and @foo dont' work.

I'm looking for some better way to handle these situational links that load on every page (as they are part of the layout) then a giant list of if statements checking on the state of the instance variables.  Does that explain it a bit more?

Comment: Pretty tough to help you without some more context. Your use of User, Foo and Bar obfuscates your intent. If you provided some insight into what those objects are, then it would become more clear what you're trying to do by branching on their presence. Apparently, these objects are mutually exclusive?

Comment: I added some more detail on exactly what I'm looking for.